# Align button to the right

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I know this must be really simple but I'm trying to set a button to the right of the window using only bootstrap 4 classes. It must be in the same row as the text.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <h3 class="one">Text</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary pull-right">Button</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code is in [here](http://codepen.io/Cabeda/pen/KaXOrr)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

[Bootstrap 4 uses `.float-right`](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/#responsive) as opposed to `.pull-right` in Bootstrap 3. Also, don't forget to properly nest your rows with columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h3 class="one">Text</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary float-right">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What anyone could do wrong is put them without placing them in a row and column properly.
This one works nicely.

Answer (score 18):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <h3 class="one">Text</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary ml-auto">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.ml-auto` is Bootstraph 4's non-flexbox way of aligning things.

Comment: Adding `ml-auto` to the button class works for me in Bootstrap 4 when many other things didn't (tried various things in the button class, nav class, and ul class)

Comment: "For Bootstrap-5 we have to use ms-auto instead of ml-auto", source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65562241/1956540

Answer (score 7):

You can also use like below code.

```
<button style="position: absolute; right: 0;">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use float, the easiest and cleanest way to do it is by using an auto width column:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h3 class="one">Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary pull-right">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed to **align two or more buttons to the right**, after several attempts this worked for me:

```
 <div class="float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">First Button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Second Button</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put your script and link on the head like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="row">
        <h3 class="one">Text</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary pull-right">Button</button>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use **float:right;**:

```css
.one {
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-color: white;
   display:inline; 
}
.two {
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
.pull-right{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="row">
       <h3 class="one">Text</h3>
       <button class="btn btn-secondary pull-right">Button</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: float:right; that's what i need XD

Answer (score -1):

```
<v-btn class="float-right">  Download</v-btn>
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score -4):

The bootstrap 4.0.0 file you are getting from cdn doesn't have a pull-right (or pull-left) class. The v4 is in alpha, so there are many issues like that.

There are 2 options:

1) Reverse to bootstrap 3.3.7

2) Write your own CSS.

Comment: Was too fast with judging. Bootstrap 4 has a float-right (float-left) classes instead of pull-right (pull-left). Sorry.