# How to align the header and button on the same line using bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to position my h3 header and button on the same line

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u/bQvRA/1bobcXlcEYpsEdFVK/vJs3+T+nXLsBYJthmdBuavHvAW6UsmqO2Gd/F9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="get-quote">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 id="quote">IN HOUSE EMBROIDERY AND HEAT TRASNFER</h3> <button type="button" class="pull-right" class="btn btn-primary">Get Quote</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use two `.col-`'s, to place them on one line.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u/bQvRA/1bobcXlcEYpsEdFVK/vJs3+T+nXLsBYJthmdBuavHvAW6UsmqO2Gd/F9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="get-quote">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-12">
                <h3 id="quote">IN HOUSE EMBROIDERY AND HEAT TRASNFER</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Get Quote</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

Add `d-flex` class on `col-md-12` div.

Also add  `ml-auto` on button to right align the button

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u/bQvRA/1bobcXlcEYpsEdFVK/vJs3+T+nXLsBYJthmdBuavHvAW6UsmqO2Gd/F9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="get-quote">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 d-flex">
        <h3 id="quote">IN HOUSE EMBROIDERY AND HEAT TRASNFER</h3> 
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto">Get Quote</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "For Bootstrap-5 we have to use ms-auto instead of ml-auto", source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65562241/1956540

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display: inline-block;` for your `h3`.

```css
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="get-quote">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 id="quote">IN HOUSE EMBROIDERY AND HEAT TRASNFER</h3> <button type="button" class="pull-right" class="btn btn-primary">Get Quote</button>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  float: right;
}
```

But, you are using **Bootstrap**, so perhaps: `col-md-6` for both?

Comment: Yeah, you wrote after I added comment ;)

Comment: Thanks,  I went with col-md-6 for the both

Answer (score -1):

`h3`'s are notoriously shy and like to isolate themselves. encourage him to get out there and make friends with the button by adding `style="display:inline-block"` to `h3`'s parameters.

Comment: While I appreciate the cute sentiment, it'd be a lot more helpful to the OP if you explained using the correct terminology. (Particularly as it's not entirely clear what you mean when you say they like to *'isolate themselves'*)

Comment: i meant they demand to sit alone in the corner in the cafeteria, unless you yell at them to stay `in-line`. come to thing of it, that whole crew of h tags are quite antisocial. it must be genetic.