# navbar - right not working in my html file

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, angular9

So I am a beginner in angular and I have to simply make a navbar.I have my bootstrap loaded in the .json file and it looks like this:-

```
 "styles": [
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"

        ],
```

whereas my code looks like this:-

```
<ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li >
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Save Data</a>
        </li>
        <li >
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Fetch Data</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

`

Output is :-
[image: output]

my save data and fetch data are not appearing on right.what is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace "navbar-right" with "ml-auto".
But still things are wrong with your code apart from "navbar-right".
It should be -

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li >
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Save Data</a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Fetch Data</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am familiar with the tutorial you are working with, so I guess you are creating a dropdown menu, this should be the complete code for it-

```
 <ul class = "navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#"  role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Manage
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Save Data</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fetch Data</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

These existing questions might help -

- [Bootstrap NavBar with left, center or right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-or-right-aligned-items#:%7E:text=Now%20that%20Bootstrap%204%20has%20flexbox%2C%20Navbar%20alignment,be%20used%20to%20align%20Navbar%20content%20as%20needed.)
- [ml-auto is not pushing navbar links to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022773/ml-auto-is-not-pushing-navbar-links-to-the-right)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be also nice to explain to OP why his original code doesn't work (`ul` in `ul` nesting, etc.)

Comment: Thankyou! Can you explain why ml auto specifically is used? :')

Comment: ml-auto is "margin left : auto" ; I guess it has to do with the fact that bootstrap 4 uses flexbox to handle layouts instead of floats.